# Submitting iMessage sticker pack requires iPad screenshots?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, app-store-connect, imessage

I built a basic sticker pack extension (not a full app) in Xcode, logged into iTunes Connect, created a new iOS app, submitted description and screenshots for iMessage part of the app info, submitted my sticker pack bundle trough Xcode **but** when I try to submit the app in iTunes Connect for review it asks me in red text to provide basic iPhone/iPad screenshots and also a square iOS icon, although it's just a sticker pack extension.

What I did wrong? I don't see other sticker packs having any iPad screenshots (checked from iTunes on a Mac). I also did set the category of the app to Stickers. Do we need to provide iPad screenshots? And double the iMessage screenshots for iPhone? (Why?)

Comment: Instructions for submitting stickers pack extension are still unclear. This is a really nice post about it that try to explains. http://beckyhansmeyer.com/2016/09/08/submitting-stickers-through-itunes-connect/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have choosen `Universal` in your targets deployment info. Choose `iPhone` to not support iPads:

[image]

Comment: Ok, it's fair, thank you @shallowThought ! But what screenshots I should provide for iPhone section when it's not a standalone app? Just use the same screenshots I used for iMessage section?

Comment: Yes you should just use the same screenshots.

Comment: @shallowThought,

Your answer does not seem quite correct because I had set my Deployment target as iPhone but still iTuneConnect requires iPad screenshots before I can submit my basic sticker pack for Apple review . Apple has not provided any clear documentation on this. Looks like kind of Apple thing :)